# Current state not updated on function call

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-hooks, fetch-api

Here is part of my tech stack: React (frontend) + Django REST Framework (backend).

My problem is inside the React part.

- I'm able to retrieve data in tables (using react-table).
  I've added a column for actions (edit, delete).
- Retrieving and displaying all datas is ok with my `getAPIData` function
- My API is fully functional for GET (all or a specific record), POST, PUT, DELETE requests (tested with Postman)

However, when I click the edit button `editClick()` calls `getApiOneData()` and pass the database id to return one record in a #MyModal but the value of `oneDataAPI` is not updated :

- `getApiData()` works fine on page load and calls with `refreshlist()`
- value of `response` in `getApiOneData` function is ok
- `setOneDataAPI` is not updated neither is `oneDataAPI`

Here is the code:

`Entities.js`

```
import React, { useState, useMemo, useEffect } from "react"; 
import { variables } from "../../components/Variables"; 
import TableStandard from "../../components/Tables";

export default function Entities() { 
    const url = "ent"; 
    const caption = "Entities";
    
    const [dataAPI, setDataAPI] = useState([]); 
    const [oneDataAPI, setOneDataAPI] = useState([]);
    
    const [modalTitle, setModalTitle] = useState([]);
    
    const defaultEntData = useMemo( () => [ { id: 0, ent_name: "", ent_abbrev: "", }, ], [] );
    
    const [entData, setEntData] = useState(defaultEntData);
    
    
    const columns = useMemo( () => [ { Header: "Id", accessor: "id", }, { Header: "Name", accessor: "ent_name", }, { Header: "Abbreviation", accessor: "ent_abbrev", }, { id: "actions", Headers: "Actions", Cell: ({ row }) => ( <div> <button type="button" className="btn btn-light btn-sm mr-1" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#myModal" onClick={() => editClick(row.values.id)} > <i className="bi bi-pencil-square" role="img" aria-label="Edit" ></i> </button> <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger btn-sm mr-1" onClick={() => deleteClick(row.values.id)} > <i className="bi bi-trash" role="img" aria-label="Delete"></i> </button> </div> ), }, ], [] );
    
    
    const getApiData = async () => { 
        const response = await fetch(variables.API_URL + url).then((response) => response.json() );
    
        if (response) {
          setDataAPI(response);
        }
        
    };
    
    const getApiOneData = async (kid) => { 
        const response = await fetch(variables.API_URL + url + "/" + kid).then( (response) => response.json() );
    
        if (response) {
          // update the state
          setOneDataAPI(response);
        }
    
    };
    
    const refreshList = async () => { getApiData(); };
    
    const handleChange = async (e) => { 
        setEntData((previousState) => { return { ...previousState, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }; }); };
    
    const editClick = async (kid) => { 
        setModalTitle("Modifier une entité");
    
        getApiOneData(kid);
    
        console.log(oneDataAPI);
    
        // setEntData({
        //   id: props.id,
        //   ent_name: props.ent_name,
        //   ent_abbrev: props.ent_abbrev,
        // });
        
    };
    
    useEffect(() => { getApiData(); }, []);
    
    // Render the UI for your table return ( <div className="container"> <div> <h2>Entities</h2> </div>
    
      {/* Add new button */}
      <button
        type="button"
        className="btn btn-primary m-2 float-end"
        data-bs-toggle="modal"
        data-bs-target="#myModal"
        onClick={() => addClick()}
      >
        <i className="bi bi-plus-square"></i>
      </button>
    
      <div>
        <TableStandard caption={caption} columns={columns} data={dataAPI} />
      </div>
    
      {/* {editModal()} */}
      <div className="modal modal-xl" id="myModal" tabIndex="-1">
        <div className="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable">
          <div className="modal-content">
            {/* Header */}
            <div className="modal-header">
              <h5 className="modal-title">{modalTitle}</h5>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn-close"
                data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              ></button>
            </div>
    
            {/* Body */}
            <div className="modal-body">
              <div className="input-group mb-3">
                <span className="input-group-text">Entity</span>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  //   key="ent_name"
                  name="ent_name"
                  value={entData.ent_name}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="input-group mb-3">
                <span className="input-group-text">Alias</span>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  //   key="ent_abbrev"
                  name="ent_abbrev"
                  value={entData.ent_abbrev}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                />
              </div>
              
    
              
    
            {/* Footer */}
            <div className="modal-footer">
              {entData.id === 0 ? (
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-primary float-start"
                  onClick={() => createClick()}
                >
                  Créer
                </button>
              ) : null}
              {entData.id !== 0 ? (
                <button
                  type="button"
                  className="btn btn-primary float-start"
                  onClick={() => updateClick()}
                >
                  Mettre à jour
                </button>
              ) : null}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
); }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fundamental mechanism of React you are missing : a setState function is never changing the associated value but will trigger a rerender of the component.

```
const Component = ()=>{
  const [myVar, setMyVar] = useState(0)
  useEffect(()=>{
    setMyVar(1);
    console.log(myVar); // display 0 then rerender the component with myVar = 1
  }, [])
  return <>{myVar}</>
}
```

To apply this to your case :

```
 const editClick = async (kid) => { 
        setModalTitle("Modifier une entité");
        getApiOneData(kid); // this function is setting state oneDataAPI
        console.log(oneDataAPI); // as explained, oneDataAPI being a state, still the old value and then component is refresh with the new value
    };
```

You can use a useEffect to tell to your component "when the oneDataAPI is updated... (do the expected behaviour)"

```
const editClick = async (kid) => {
  //...
  getApiOneData(kid);
};

useEffect(()=>{
   console.log("oneDataAPI is updated")
}, [oneDataAPI])
```

Comment: Yes indeed, state is still a bit confusing to manage currently.
I was able to obtain the updated value in this useEffect but my editClick function is still not working. Should I put the code in the useEffect ? Pretty sure I cannot put useEffect in editClick, would be a nonsense ...

Comment: I mean I must deal with passing values to setEntData (currently commented in my post)

Comment: Indeed, the useEffect should always be at the root of your component (not in editClick function) but it will be triggered every time setOneDataAPI is called. So you can call setEntData there.

Comment: You made the decision to have 2 states storing the same thing (entData being a transformed version from oneDataAPI). My comment explain you how to sync entData with oneDataAPI. However, this might be simplified by removing your state oneDataAPI. Just consider the function getApiOneData return the api response then you setEntData in your editClick function.